# Am I putting too much code into my customadapter for listview?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, concept

I think I have too much code in my CustomAdapter for my listview. Is it normal to have multiple onclicks, db editing, and popup window code in a CustomAdapter?

I've looked into how to move the code into the activity class that houses the listview, but it's either impossible or highly complicated. I don't really have a ton of experience so its difficult to follow some of the more technical coding methods.

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the code...

Comment: seems like not so well written code, but without any line...

Comment: It sounds like you're putting a lot of business logic in the Adapter when it's only function is to return Views that represent the data. In my opinion, yes, you're putting too much in it.  Practice separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

> I've looked into how to move the code into the activity class that houses the listview, but it's either impossible or highly complicated

The only reason it would be complicated is that you are doing too much within the adapter.

If you did want to move the code into the activity, the way would be to use interfaces

For example, with some given `Item` class that you have in the adapter.

```
// ... BaseAdapter, ArrayAdapter, RecyclerView.Adapter... Same difference
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public interface OnItemActionListener {
        void onItemEdited(Item x);
        void onItemAdded(Item x);
        void onItemClicked(Item x);
        // etc.
    }

    public OnItemActionListener listener; // should make private with a setter method

    ...

        // somewhere in the adapter
        Item x = getItem(position);

        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onItemClicked(item);
        }

    ...

}
```

And your Activity could implement that interface.

```
public YourActivity extends Activity 
    implements YourAdapter.OnItemActionListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(Item x) {
        Log.d("item click", String.valueOf(x));
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemAdded(Item x) {
        Log.d("item added", String.valueOf(x));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView... ;

        adapter = new YourAdapter... ;
        adapter.listener = this; // Should use a setter method instead
    }

}
```

---

Regarding this

> Is it normal to have multiple onclicks

You only need one interface for `onClick(View v)` and you can check `v.getId()` against any `R.id` value to see what is being clicked.

Comment: is YourActivity: 1.The activity that contains the listview and the listview adapter or 2.A different activity just for handling onclicks or 3.The activity that you want to switch to save if the button leads to an edit transaction page.

Comment: I intended it to be the one with the listview since that's where the adapter is contained